# Codenameone Enum.valueof String throws IllegalArgument exception on iOS 9

Tags: ios, codenameone

In codenameone, when using valueOf(String s) on enum throws IllegalArgument exception: No enum const on iPhone5, iOS9, but works fine on simulator and Android. It worked fine 3-4 weeks ago. Type OK in the text box and press the button, on simulator fine, if you build it and run it for iOS9 - you will get the exception.

Bellow a snapshot code to test:

```
public class MyApplication {

private Form current;
private Resources theme;
enum popo { OK, ERROR,EXCEPTION};

public void init(Object context) {
    theme = UIManager.initFirstTheme("/theme");

    // Pro only feature, uncomment if you have a pro subscription
    // Log.bindCrashProtection(true);
}

public void start() {
    if(current != null){
        current.show();
        return;
    }

    Form hi = new Form("Hi World");
    hi.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    final TextArea input = new TextArea();
    Button testr = new Button("Touch me");

    testr.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
            popo q = popo.valueOf(input.getText());
            Dialog.show("title", 
                    "just found string = "+input.getText()+" \nthat gives enum = "+q.toString()
                    , "OK", null);
        }
    });


    hi.addComponent(BorderLayout.CENTER, input);
    hi.addComponent(BorderLayout.SOUTH,testr);
    hi.show();

}

public void stop() {
    current = Display.getInstance().getCurrent();
}

public void destroy() {
}

}
```

Many thanks,
Goran.

Comment: this is not swift, cross platform?

Comment: sorry - forgot to mention it is on codenameone .

Answer (score 0):

Enum's `values()` and related calls aren't implemented in Codename One. The crux of the issue is that they fail during obfuscation (for Android) and require some reflection code generated by the `javac` tool.

The workaround is to use something like this:

```
enum popo {OK("OK"), ERROR("ERROR),EXCEPTION("EXCEPTION");
public popo(String value) {
   this.value = value;
}
String value;
};
```

Then use `myPopo.value`.

Comment: I rewrote valueOf and using popo[] l = popo.values(); and it works, it shouldn't be working ?

Comment: Did it work for you on an iOS device? As far as I recall it shouldn't but I might be wrong here.